# How to pass arguments to the docker run command dynamically

Tags: docker, parameter-passing, supervisord, docker-run

I have a docker file like this and I have to pass the arguments to docker run command dynamically

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENV IRONHIDE_SOURCE /var/tmp/ironhide-setup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  openssh-server supervisor cron syslog-ng-core logrotate libapr1 libaprutil1 liblog4cxx10 libxml2 psmisc xsltproc ntp
RUN sed -i -E 's/^(\s*)system\(\);/\1unix-stream("\/dev\/log");/' /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
ADD ironhide-setup/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor & mkdir -p /opt/ibm/
COPY /ironhide-setup/etc/cron.d/* /etc/cron.d
ADD ironhide-setup $IRONHIDE_SOURCE
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/default
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
ENV IRONHIDE_ROOT /usr/ironhide
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/ironhide/lib
ENV IH_ROOT /usr/ironhide
ENV IRONHIDE_BACKUP_PATH /var/tmp/ironhide-backup
ENV PATH $IH_ROOT/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'PS1="[AppConnect-Container@\h \w]: "' >> ~/.bashrc
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

and my supervisord.conf is this

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:cron]
command = cron -f -L 15
priority=1

[program:syslog-ng]
command=/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid --no-caps

[program:InstallCastIron]
command = %(ENV_IRONHIDE_SOURCE)s/scripts/var_setup
priority=2
```

I have to pass the arguments to "docker run" command so internally one of the script under scripts location should be using the argument when the docker container comes up.

Please let me know how can I do this and how to achieve" this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this feat, you will need to use environment variables.

First you will need to make sure that the service you want to pass arguments to consumes those environment variables.

Second you will need to have those variables defined in your dockerfile. [For example:-](https://github.com/ahab94/AddMyKeyPlease/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Third make sure you use entrypoint script [For example:-](https://github.com/ahab94/AddMyKeyPlease/blob/master/entrypoint.sh)

Last you can use the `docker run -e DEFINE_THOSE_VARS=<value>`. Or alternatively you can use docker-compose like [this](https://github.com/ahab94/AddMyKeyPlease/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml)

You can traverse through my repo [here](https://github.com/ahab94/AddMyKeyPlease) which achieves this feat.

Please feel free to ask any Question.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes but you would spawn `supervisord` in your entrypoint file instead, after the variables are defined properly in your entrypoint file.

Comment: It should look something like...

#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/supervisord

Comment: Like here 
https://github.com/ahab94/AddMyKeyPlease/blob/master/entrypoint.sh

But in a different context.